# Navigation tabs with fragments to which to add another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a recording app which I recently convert it on tabs layout. One tab is called Recorder and the other one is called Player. Both are integrated in a `SherlockFragmentActivity`. Each tab represent a fragment with its own layout. The Player fragment has a list with recordings and clicking on an item will open another activity which plays the recording.

All I want is to get rid of that activity and to incorporate a player control directly in the Player fragment. Basically I want to add another fragment in the player fragment (at bottom of the recordings list I want to add a fragment with play, pause, stop, etc buttons). Is it a good practice to add a fragment into another one? If not, how should I add that player control panel?(without simply adding the buttons in the same layout as the list is).

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions titles with keywords like Android, Blackberry, iOs, the tags at the bottom are enough.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to add a fragment into another one?

Sure if you decide that you want this, that's why nested fragments have been introduced on the platform. Based on your situation and due to the use of fragments as tabs I wouldn't use a nested fragment, I would just insert the controls in the fragment's layout and change the visibility for that part as the user plays/stops stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a layout with those controls and assigning to it a separate class (maybe I will use the <include> layout option)

Comment: @AlexandruCircus The `include` tag is an option, you could also use a `ViewStub` to delay the loading of those views until the user actually request them.